# Sending a Json in get request in java

Tags: spring, spring-boot, webclient, spring-webclient

There is an API which sends back data on get request from a database. The database is huge, so the data we need, we have to specify it in json. So actually we have to send a json with get request to get back the desired data.

It has been implemented in python `requests.get(url, headers, json)`
I want to do this in Java/Spring.

I tried webclient but it did not work.

Comment: Hi i suggest you start with the Spring Webflux spring tutorial - https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/ , after that the Spring JPA tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ , this should give you some insight on how to wire things up.

Comment: Yeah thanks @Kevvvvyp I have gone through the basic, but it has not solved the problem. is it possible to send a json or payload/body in the get request in java? i did that in python

Comment: Typically GET requests don't contain a body which is probably why you don't see an expliclt method for it on Webclient.get() https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec.html 

But you could make use of webclient.method passing HttpMethod.GET as a parameter, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec.html

Comment: It helped, thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To supply a body as part of a GET request using [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) you would need to use webclient.method([HttpMethod.GET](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpMethod.html#GET))